# Cannot reassign struct member values

Tags: c, struct

I have this code in my `main.c` file, which assigns style members to the button struct:

```c
    struct SCGUI_Button button = scgui_new_button();

    button.style = (SCGUI_ButtonStyle) {
        .background_color = new_color(255, 0, 0),

        .hover = {
            .font_family = "res/Cursive.ttf",
            .background_color = new_color(255, 0, 0) //I defined the color RIGHT HERE (button.style.hover.background_color)
        }
    };

    //Update function (for hover)
    scgui_draw_button(&button, CENTER);
```

In my `button.c` file where I define these functions, I have this code:

```c
struct SCGUI_Button scgui_new_button() {

    //Default initialization values
    struct SCGUI_Button button = {
        .style = {
            .background_color = new_color(200, 200, 200),
            .font_color = new_color(0, 0, 0),
            .font_family = "res/Roboto.ttf",
            .font_size = 24,

            .hover = {
                .background_color = new_color(220, 220, 220),
                .font_color = new_color(20, 20, 20),
                .font_family = "res/Roboto.ttf",
                .font_size = 24
            }
        }
    };

    return button;
}


void scgui_draw_button(struct SCGUI_Button *self) {
    if (button_hovered(self->area, app.mouse_pos.x, app.mouse_pos.y)) {
        self->state.hovered = true;

        //Attempt to set actual button styles to hover styles (either provided in main.c, or if not provided, set to the default values in the button initialization function)
        self->style = (SCGUI_ButtonStyle) {
            .background_color = self->style.hover.background_color,
            .font_color = self->style.hover.font_color,
            .font_family = self->style.hover.font_family == NULL ? "res/Roboto.ttf" : self->style.hover.font_family,
            .font_size = self->style.hover.font_size == 0 ? 24 : self->style.hover.font_size,
        };

    }
}
```

However, here's the problem. The hover function works for sure, but setting the styles doesn't. Whenever I hover over the button, the button just turns black. My hypothesis here is that non-initialized color members default to 0, so all styles are being set to RGB (0, 0, 0). However, why these struct style members aren't being set correctly is a mystery to me. Can you not set a struct style like I did in the `scgui_draw_button()` function when hovered? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "My hypothesis here is that non-initialized color members default to 0, so all styles are being set to RGB (0, 0, 0)" You should check that with your favourite debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the structure assignment using the compound literal, all the fields not explicitly given a value are zeroed:

```
button.style = (SCGUI_ButtonStyle) { … };
```

After the assignment, `button.style.font_family` is a null pointer, `button.style.font_size` is `0` (the `button.style.font_color` is unchanged, but that's mostly accidental).  The font colour and font size in the hover section are also zeroed.

You need to do individual member assignments in the first fragment:

```
button.style.background_color = new_color(255, 0, 0);
button.style.hover.font_family = "res/Cursive.ttf";
button.style.hover.background_color = new_color(255, 0, 0);
```

This preserves the members not otherwise mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! I used the first method initially just because I thought it looked better and unfortunately didn't know there was a difference.